# concatenate datframes iteratively on dataframe names that ends with '*'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, concatenation

For example, say I have several dataframes in current instance:

```
alldfs = [var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]
```

Out:
['df',
'df_01_W',
'df_01_W_pvt',
'df_01_X',
'df_01_X_pvt',
'df_02_W',
'df_02_W_pvt',
'df_03',
'df_03_pvt',
'df_04_W',
'df_04_W_pvt',
'df_04_X',
'df_04_X_pvt']

I would like to concatenate iteratively only the daframes for which the name ends with '_pvt' in one unique df.
,
I shall concatenate : df_01_W_pvt, df_01_X_pvt, df_02_W_pvt, df_03_pvt, df_04_W_pvt, df_04_X_pvt

This could be done easily with this command:

```
merged = pd.concat([df_01_W_pvt, df_01_X_pvt, df_02_W_pvt, df_03_pvt, df_04_W_pvt, df_04_X_pvt], sort=False)
```

But I would like to find how I could concatenate datframes iteratively on dataframe names that ends with '_pvt'.

If I could have your highlights, that will be truly appreciated.

Thanks in advance and kindest regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
new_df = pd.concat([globals()[x] for x in alldfs if x.endswith('_pvt')])
```